# drawing a circle around many points with different radius

Tags: plot, gnuplot, geometry

I can draw a circle around a given point (x,y) with a command like flowing (here for example point is at (X=5,Y=7) and the circle have a radius R=2.73):

```
set object 1 circle at 5,7 size first 2.73 fc rgb "navy"
```

Now, if I have many points (in a txt file where each line is "x y") and I want to draw a circle around each point with different specified radius. Should I repeat the command "set object i circle at Xi,Yi size first Ri fc rgb "navy"" for each point i ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may want to use the `with circles` option.  If you have a data file with three columns (x y radius), the following command will plot circles with radii from the file at each point:

```
 plot 'datafile' u 1:2:3 with circles
```

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/circles.html

Comment: Note that you can set the fillstyle:  `set style fill ...`, but this is exactly the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop in gnuplot for multiple circles.

```
do for[k=1:20]{
   set object k circle front at k*3,0 size 1 fillcolor rgb "black" lw 1  
}
```

This will create 20 circles at x points (3,6,9...) of radius 1. Please keep in mind to set the object count with the loop variable too ("object k").

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30401864)