# How do you draw a circle using GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to draw a circle with a 0.06 diameter using GNU plot. I've been searching for a while and can't find any solution. Just a simple circle that will act as an indicator for points to be plotted after if it goes out pf bounds that specific circle.

I need something like this but the diameter would be **-0.06** to **0.06**.

[image]

Here's the code for the sample image:

```
gnuplot> set parametric

    dummy variable is t for curves, u/v for surfaces
gnuplot> set size square
gnuplot> set xrange [-1:1]
gnuplot> set yrange [-1:1]
gnuplot> plot [0:2*pi] sin(t),cos(t)
```

Comment: `set object circle`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11145664/2604213

Comment: @Christoph I can't make it work, there is no circle showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using an object is the good solution, but just as an addition:*

The parametric equation of a circle centered on the origin is simply:

(x(t) = r.cos(t), y(t) = r.sin(t))

Where r is the radius of the circle and t the parameter.

So for a circle of radius 0.6, simply type:

```
set parametric
set size square
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
plot [0:2*pi] 0.6*sin(t), 0.6*cos(t)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Done using this code:

```
set terminal png size 1000,1000; 
set output 'test.png';
set xrange [-0.06:0.06]
set yrange [-0.06:0.06]
set size square
set object 1 circle front at 0,0size 0.06 fillcolor rgb "black" lw 1
plot "data.txt", "data2.txt"
```

Thank you @Christoph for pointing me to the right direction.